# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of null (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript

My code is now working and triggering popup but I'm getting an error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
at HTMLDocument.mouseEvent

```html
const mouseEvent = e => {
    if (!e.toElement && !e.relatedTarget) {
        document.removeEventListener('mouseout', mouseEvent);
               document.querySelector('.exit_intent_popup').classList.add('activate_exit_intent');
                                document.querySelector('.exit_intent_popup_bottom').classList.add('activate_exit_intent');
                       
    }
};

document.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseEvent);
```

I'm do not understand what's wrong in here or how to resolve this error?

Comment: seems there's no element with class `exit_intent_popup_bottom` or `exit_intent_popup` - which one? only you know - by the way - why the bizarre indentation? makes the code unreadable

Comment: check your css class

Comment: Correct there is none of these classes at the moment, however once mouse goes outside the scrip one or the other class is dynamically added to the normally hidden div which then through css creates popup effect...